# How do I find the next permutation of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am given a list of numbers from 1 to N, How do I find the next permutation of a given list?

For example:

```
lst = [2, 1, 4, 3]
```

the next permutation would be

```
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

What I did was use intertools

```
import itertools
lst2 = list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

then find the index of the given list and return +1 that index

However, is there other way to do this without using intertools? I was thinking there is a pattern on how these lists are arranged in ascending order.

Comment: Permutations are random unless you define a rule by which any new member of the sequence is positioned, so there's no `next` per se in terms of legitimacy.

Comment: Why do you think `[2, 3, 1, 4]` is the next after `[2, 1, 4, 3]`?

Comment: Assuming the permutations are generated by an algorithm `perm` you can always just do something like `next(islice(perm([2, 1, 4, 3]), 1, 2))` to get the next permutation in the sequence of permutations that `perm` would generate quite efficiently. The assumption here is that `perm` yields an iterator. Another option is to just shuffle the list.

Comment: I want them to be in order how the intertools.permutations sequence them. For example: permutation of (1,2,3) would be listed in this order: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]. so if I'm given (2, 3, 1) I should be able to return (3, 2, 1)

Comment: The problem is called "next lexicographic permutation", there is a simple algorithm for it which can be found by searching.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223349/python-implementation-for-next-permutation-in-stl